# Questions regarding disk format

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, install, disk-format, formatting

I'm doing a fresh install of Yosemite on my mac, but stopped at format step: I noticed various options:

- plain format
- encrypted
- case sensitive

So, I'd like to know:

- Is it possible to install Yosemite on an encrypted partition? If
     yes, there are downsides?
- Is this equivalent to installing on unencrypted disk and perform
  encryption from OS with FileVault? If not, may you explain the
  difference?
- I'm tempted to choose Case Sensitive to have a more "true Unix"
  environment. May this cause issues with OS and apps?

I googled, but those answers are rather difficult to find.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very detailed answer. I wonder why you don't have posted it as regular answer, I'd have accepted it. Meanwhile, installing the OS on my machine proved itself difficult. I posted another question, take a look at it if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Yosemite on an encrypted partition. To use encryption, you also have to use core storage. If you do not use encryption, then the use of core storage is optional. If you encrypt after installing without core storage, then a conversion to core storage will take place. Fusion drives require the use of core storage. Yosemite can only be installed on a partition that is case insensitive. Personally, I have avoided using core storage. I do not see any advantages to using it unless you have to.